# Website in Angular, django and Firebase

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

Is it possible to create a web application which uses Angular as view, django as Controller and firebase Nosql database as modal. If it is possible what are gonna be the benefits and drawbacks of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question!
Anyone has an answer to it?
interested too